# dll and R DLLRegisteredRoutines empty

Tags: r, dll

I have a problem with loading/using a 32-bit DLL. I am using this web site as advice: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dynload.html

I want to load the swedll32.dll (C: which is compiled using: Visual Studio and another version is done with MinGW). The documentation (to use the dll is here: ftp://ftp.astro.com/pub/swisseph/doc/swisseph.htm#_Toc502931278 )

```
x <- dyn.load("swedll32.dll")
x
```

gives:

```
DLL name: swedll32
Filename: C:/Users/VRHome/Documents/R/ARCHAECOSMO/ARCHAEOCOSMO/swedll32.dll
Dynamic lookup: TRUE
```

It looks to be loaded:

```
getLoadedDLLs()
#...
swedll32       C:/Users/VRHome/Documents/R/ARCHAECOSMO/ARCHAEOCOSMO/swedll32.dll
#...
swedll32              TRUE
```

But:

```
getDLLRegisteredRoutines(x)
```

gives:

```
 data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

and using https://darrenjw.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/calling-c-code-from-r/ to run a function in the dll:

```
.C("swe_get_tid_acc") 
Error in .C("swe_get_tid_acc") : 
C symbol name "swe_get_tid_acc" not in load table
```

So the issue might be that the swedll32 routines (C-functions) are not registered ('data frame' is 0 by 0)...
So perhaps I need to register the functions in similar way (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Microsoft_Visual_Basic_2) as VBA? But how, what information do I need to ask from the dll author?

Any hints to get this to work is welcome. I am new to using DLLs as part of other code (I use this dll in VBA for Excel plug-in). Thanks in advance

All the best,

Victor

Comment: the compilers used by Visual Studio and R are different. you will not be able to dll built from Visual Studio in R.

Comment: I also have a dll compiled by MinGW, would that be possible (although I get the same results: no function names in the getDLLRegisteredRoutines(x). What compiler would be needed to get this dll into R?

Comment: i also don't have much experience nor success in building shared lib as well. this might be useful for u: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools//goodies/sources/README.txt